# TreeView databind to list of list of list

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am new to WPF and I am stuck in creating a Treeview that is bound to a list of lists of list, etc, the number of childnodes can increase as needed. I have created two HierarchicalDataTemplates to test off the code, but the child nodes are not appearing

My tree view is defined as

```
<telerik:RadTabItem Header="Lookup Sets">
    <telerik:RadTreeView IsLoadOnDemandEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AttributeLookupSetConversions}">
        <telerik:RadTreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cm:AttributeLookupSetConversion}">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerikDocking:RadSplitContainer}}, Path=DataContext.UpdateSelectionCommand}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cm:AttributeConversion}">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerikDocking:RadSplitContainer}}, Path=DataContext.UpdateSelectionCommand}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadTreeView.Resources>
    </telerik:RadTreeView>
</telerik:RadTabItem>
```

Is there something I am missing or will I have to create the nodes in code? I have a tabControl  that has treeViews of lists of lists, the problem is one tab can contain items of another treeView that are linked relationally by an Id, so if I have say fro example

```
stundents
    -Student1
        -Course 1
        -Course 2
           - Department 1
     -Student 2
         -Course 6
            Department12

Course
    -Qualification 1
        -WorkType
```

Comment: missing `ItemsSource ` in template

Comment: I already have an item template on the parent , do i need one on the child node template as well?

Comment: Try sample from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: I have tried the MSDN link and still nothing appears

Comment: can you also paste code of binding lists?

Comment: I have updated the question with more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class as the root of all your ltems, which has a `DisplayName` and an observablecollection of other `Item`s:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    string _displayText;
    public string DisplayText { get { return _displayText; } set { _displayText = value; RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayText"); } }

    ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items { get { return _items; } set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Items"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

Any other type (Student, Teacher, Course, Department, etc.) must be derived from this class. They might have their specific properties too.

```
public class Student : Item
{
}
public class Course : Item
{
}
public class Qualification : Item
{
}
```

Note that if you have two types of `Course` class (with different Inner list of items), create two separate classes for them.

Now, you should populate the observableCollection in the view model propertly, and everything will be taken care of in a TreeView such as the following:

```
<TreeView DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```